# wsimport and wsdl file with external namespaces

Tags: jax-ws, wsimport

I am using Oracle's JDK 1.7 **wsimport** tool to build a client for a **JAX-WS** service using the top-down approach and I would like to understand what happens when I feed it with a *.**wsdl** file that uses or imports namespaces defined on the web. Will the **wsimport** tool try to de-reference and obtain the corresponding **xsd** files? Is there a way to feed it the schema files it needs from the local filesystem so that one can support offline builds?

E.g. the top of my **wsdl** file reads like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="IVOARegistrySearch"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:adql="http://www.ivoa.net/xml/ADQL/v1.0"
             xmlns:tns="http://www.ivoa.net/wsdl/RegistrySearch/v1.0"
             targetNamespace="http://www.ivoa.net/wsdl/RegistrySearch/v1.0">
   <types>
      <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:tns="http://www.ivoa.net/wsdl/RegistrySearch/v1.0"
                 targetNamespace="http://www.ivoa.net/wsdl/RegistrySearch/v1.0">
```

Do I understand right that the **wsimport** will try to download, e.g. the schema file for the **adql** namespace preffix:

```
http://www.ivoa.net/xml/ADQL/v1.0
```

... over the web and is there a way to feed it this and other transitive schema dependencies myself so that it doesn't have to access them over the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way: use a catalog file. E.g. [as in here](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/catalog-support.html) or as described in [this blog post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html)